# Recording audio in flash

Tags: flash, video, audio

in flash I know there is the flash.media.Video class. This class can capture video recording, here's its documentation:

> The Video class displays live or
>   recorded video in an application
>   without embedding the video in your
>   SWF file. This class creates a Video
>   object in an Adobe Flash or Adobe Flex
>   interface that plays either of the
>   following kinds of video: recorded FLV
>   files stored on a server or locally,
>   or live video captured from a user's
>   computer. A Video object is a display
>   object on the application's display
>   list and represents the visual space
>   in which the video runs in a user
>   interface

What's special about this is the fact that I can capture live video and send it onwards to another application. MY questions is... Is there the same class for audio recording? I'd like to capture sound from a user microphone. From what I see the flash.media.Sound does not let me equire local audio stream (like audio recorded from the user's microphone). 
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class you are looking for is the Microphone class. Be aware though that both Video and Microphone require a server to do the recording. The two most popular compatible servers are Adobe Flash Media Server and the open source Red 5 server.

Comment: Have you used both those servers? Do you prefer one over the other?

Comment: Well, FMS is easier since you just use another JS variant. But Red5 is more powerful since you have the full power of java available to you. Lately I've mostly been using Red5 due to the cost issue (FMS ain't exactly cheap)

Comment: There's also the Wowza media server.