# how can i make microphone sound transfer from website open in my pc to websites open in others pc?

Tags: php, javascript, xml, audio, audio-streaming

I want to make a web page which has access to my microphone and can send my voice to anyone with another webpage open. Can anyone help me do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to use Flash for that, you can't do it in Javascript or PHP.
This should help: [Recording audio in flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1211289/recording-audio-in-flash)

You'll need to stream that back to your server, however. That will require PHP (or a similar server-side language).

The server software you received might be able to handle the audio coming back from Flash instead of using PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look at using a WebRTC platform.

WebRTC is a new API that has been drafted by the World Wide Web Consortium (W3C) and is currently supported in Chrome & Firefox desktop browsers, as well as Chrome for Android.

With WebRTC, you can have both video and audio calls done between users of your website, without requiring any plugins (such as Flash) being installed on the computer.

There are a number of Open Source libraries that will help you integrate WebRTC with very little effort:

- http://sipjs.com/
- http://sipml5.org/

The WebRTC specifications are well done. They have been written so that even in unreliable networks (high latency or high amounts of dropped packets) the quality of the audio that the server receives will be acceptable.

Google [did a presentation back in 2013](http://io13webrtc.appspot.com/#) which explains all the components. Also, html5rocks has an awesome primer article on [understanding the basics of WebRTC](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/basics/).

I hope this helps.